# What is an omega model?

Tags: terminology, definition, model-theory

I went to a seminar and a side question was if a theory had an omega model, however from the context I could not deduce the exact meaning. Does an omega model have a general meaning in mathematical logic?

Could an omega model be an $\omega$-model where its domain is of cardinality $\omega$ or could it be furthermore a unique model for such a cardinality, i.e. $\omega$-model is a countable model of the $\omega$-categorical theory?

Comment: Can you add more context? What theory?

Comment: @AsafKaragila They may have meant some theory of graphs meeting certain specific properties - e.g. it has to be directed, have a root, be a subgraph of some specific graph, etc. But the question was quite out of the context of the main talk, that is why I thought, the terminology may have a general meaning. But if you do not know, then it probably is not an established terminology.

Comment: If an omega model is not a general terminology and I cannot provide the context, perhaps I should delete the question.

Comment: No, because in set theory an $\omega$-model means a model of set theory whose natural numbers are the true natural numbers. One property of these models is that first-order statements about the natural numbers are absolute between the universe and the model. So, for example, if $\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$ is true in the universe (and it is, since there is an $\omega$-model, so there is a model), then it is true in every $\omega$-model. This means that $\omega$-models "know" about models of $\sf ZFC$ as well. So this is quite a jump from just any model of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you. Unless somebody else posts another definition, I would like to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: But I don't know if that's the right context or not. It's a weird question to ask in the context of set theory, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20441/discussion-between-david-toth-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: Let us not continue this discussion, then.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no general model-theoretic meaning to this term, so it is likely the (set-theoretic) one Asaf indicated. A model which has countable universe is called "countable model", period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be several uses of the terminology of $\omega$-model. Please, feel free to update the list below:

1. According to *Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability (1987) edition* Rogers defines on the page 392 an $\omega$-model to be a model of second-order arithmetic with the domain $\omega$ (or $\mathbb{N}$) where $0, 1, +, \times$ are interpreted in a natural sense.
2. From Asaf's comment, another possible meaning is in set theory where an $\omega$-model means a model of set theory whose natural numbers are the true natural numbers. One property of these models is that first-order statements about the natural numbers are absolute between the universe and the model. So, for example, if $Con(\mathtt{ZFC})$ is true in the universe (and it is, since there is an $\omega$-model, so there is a model), then it is true in every $\omega$-model. This means that $\omega$-models "know" about models of $\mathtt{ZFC}$ as well. So this is quite a jump from just any model of $\mathtt{ZFC}$.